# Set property not reached after an assignment

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, setter, assign

I have a property in a ViewModel of my WPF project

```cs
        private Patient _Patient;
        [BindableProperty]
        public virtual Patient Patient
        {
            get { return _Patient; }
            set
            {
                _Patient = value;
                if (FormParameter != null) FormParameter.Value.Patient = Patient;
                InitializePatientSummary();
            }
        }
```

and I have a simple command to show a confirmation popup. If YES, I reassign Patient property.

```cs
        private void DeleteMDM()
        {
            if (ConfirmDelete(Resources.PatientFile_ConfirmDelete_Title,
                    Resources.PatientFile_ConfirmDelete_Body_MDM,
                    FormParameter.Value.MDM))
            {
                var mdm = FormParameter.Value.MDM;
                //_mdmController.Remove(mdm);

                Patient = FormParameter.Value.Tumor.Patient;
                ShowTumorImpl(FormParameter.Value.Tumor);
                FormParameter.Value.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.Tumor);
            }
        }
```

This line `_mdmController.Remove(mdm);` is commented because it's an async operation and I would see if it can be the source of the issue but it doesn't.
Before assignee, I checked in the Immediate window `Patient == FormParameter.Value.Tumor.Patient` and it returns false.
**FYI**, I'm using DevExpress framework and this ViewModel doesn't have the [POCOViewModel] attribute.

It's clearly a basic operation but I can't find why the patient is not updated

Comment: You have stepped into your code to see that `Patient = FormParameter.Value.Tumor.Patient;` is actually executed?

Comment: I put breakpoint before assignment in Delete method and in the Set method. Never break in Set

Comment: When the debugger stops at the first breakpoint, step into the assignment and see what it does.

Comment: it does nothing more with the step into

Comment: Not sure what that means. *Step into* does not step into the setter? What else is it doing?

Comment: Why is the property declared `virtual`? Are you overriding it somewhere?

Comment: Debugging with step into or step over have the same effect : I don't pass in the setter neither any other method. The property is virtual because it's a devexpress convention to be able to bind it. It's not override elsewhere

Comment: I'm not familiar with DevExpress, but since you are saying that "this ViewModel doesn't have the [POCOViewModel] attribute", what happens if you remove `[BindableProperty]`?

Comment: it assigns if I remove the BindableProperty attribute...I have to check if there's no side effects now

Comment: As far as I understand the BindableProperty attribute only makes sense in a class marked as POCOViewModel.